# Foreign key to multiple tables using function and check constraint, or constraint trigger?

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple problem. Please don't ask why.

I have two tables, data1 & data2. They both have primary key id columns. The values in each are guaranteed to be unique across BOTH tables. This is enforced by check constraints.

I have a third table (data3) that has a column that should only contain values that exist in either data1.id or data2.id. I can't use a regular foreign key to enforce this. So I wrote a function that does this via a check constraint.

Is there a better way to do this using a trigger constraint?

```
drop schema if exists test cascade;
create schema test;

CREATE FUNCTION test.right_bit_shift()
    RETURNS bigint IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS
'SELECT 2::bigint';

create or replace function test.ufn_get_type_id(id bigint) returns bigint as $$
select id >> 2;
$$ language sql
;

create table test.data1(name text);
alter table test.data1 add column id bigint primary key constraint id_chk check(test.ufn_get_type_id(id) =1) no inherit ;

create table test.data2(name text);
alter table test.data2 add column id bigint primary key constraint id_chk check(test.ufn_get_type_id(id) =0) no inherit ;

insert into test.data1(id, name) values(5,'101');
insert into test.data2(id, name) values(1,'001');

create table test.table_lookup(type_id bigint, table_name text);

insert into test.table_lookup(type_id, table_name)
values
(1, 'test.data1'),
(0, 'test.data2');    


create or replace function test.ufn_get_existence_sql(_id bigint) returns text as $$
    select
            'select exists(select 1 from '||table_name||' where id = '||_id||');'
    from test.table_lookup where type_id = test.ufn_get_type_id(_id);
    $$
language sql;


create or replace function test.ufn_id_exists (id_to_check bigint) returns boolean as $$
    declare res bool;
begin
    execute test.ufn_get_existence_sql(id_to_check) into res;
    return res;
end;
$$
    language plpgsql;

create table test.data3(name text, fk_id bigint constraint fk_id check ( test.ufn_id_exists(fk_id) ));
```

Comment: Why can't you  use foreign constraint?

Comment: @KedarLimaye If you think that it is possible to use a foreign key, then please provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I found this

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75613/disable-all-constraints-and-table-checks-while-restoring-a-dump/75635#75635

It states that check constraints are supposed to be immutable, and my check constraint is certainly not. It can cause issues with restoring dumps etc.

So it seems that the best approach is an insert and update trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this using triggers. Define a trigger that fires before insert or update on table `data3` and checks if the reference column in data3 is present in data1.id or data2.id. You could raise an exception if they are not.

A simpler way to do this would be to add foreign constraints using as many columns and as many foreign keys as there are reference tables. In table 3, you can add a data2_id column that has a foreign key reference to data2.id, and another column data3_id that has a foreign key reference to data3.id. These columns have to be nullable because while data2_id is not null, data3_id is null.

Comment: While using multiple columns works for some tables, I can't prevent nulls using that approach.